# DELPHI Fill a listbox with the results of ADO Query

Tags: mysql, delphi, ado

have been reading through all associated threads but no solution posted to help me with Delphi.

Quite simply, i have a MySQL table called Story and i want to extract specific fields from this - and hence populate list box.

From other posts, i've used the following...

```
adoqMenu.Close;
adoqMenu.SQL.Text := 'SELECT StoryID, Story Description, Completion Date FROM Story';
try
  adoqMenu.Open;
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  while not adoqMenu.Eof do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(adoqMenu.Fields[0].AsString);
    adoqMenu.Next;
  end;
finally
  adoqMenu.Close;
end;
```

This only gives me the first field...grr. Quite simply, how can i change this so that the fields stated in the SELECT clause appear in the listbox as is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only see one field because you are only reading out one field (`adoqMenu.Fields[0]`).  Simply read out the other fields as well:

```
adoqMenu.Close;
adoqMenu.SQL.Text := 'SELECT StoryID, Story Description, Completion Date FROM Story';
adoqMenu.Open;
try
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;

  while not adoqMenu.Eof do
  begin
    Value1 := adoqMenu.Fields[0].AsString;
    Value2 := adoqMenu.Fields[1].AsString;
    Value3 := adoqMenu.Fields[2].AsString;

    // use Values as needed.  Format the ListBox text however
    // you want to show all three values...
    ListBox1.Items.Add(...);

    adoqMenu.Next;
  end;
finally
  adoqMenu.Close;
end;
```

Depending on your actual needs (which you did not explain), a multi-column `TListView` in `vsReport` mode may be a better choice than a `TListBox`:

```
adoqMenu.Close;
adoqMenu.SQL.Text := 'SELECT StoryID, Story Description, Completion Date FROM Story';
adoqMenu.Open;
try
  ListView1.Items.Clear;

  while not adoqMenu.Eof do
  begin
    Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := adoqMenu.Fields[0].AsString;
    Item.SubItems.Add(adoqMenu.Fields[1].AsString);
    Item.SubItems.Add(adoqMenu.Fields[2].AsString);
    adoqMenu.Next;
  end;
finally
  adoqMenu.Close;
end;
```

Comment: In your first answer...what do i put in the listbox1.items.add(...) ?  I tried   listbox1.items.add(value1,value2,value3) but got 'Out of bounds' error?

Comment: @user3396486 You can join strings with `ListBox1.Items.Add(Value1+Value2+Value3)` but what you wrote in your comment wouldn't be causing an out of bounds error. Indeed it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile.  My SQL query should return the following results:  1, Peter & Jane, 12/1/2015; 2, A boy's tale, 25/4/2012; 3, 'The scared fox', 23/1/2015;       ...i'm just simply trying to show this in a listbox.

Comment: @user3396486: as I said, you can format the strings however you want, the ListBox does not care. For example: `ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%s, %s, %s', [Value1, Value2, Value3]));`